# Entity Framework get all models for a list of models

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have three models: Quiz, Question, and Answer.

```
public class Quiz 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Question>? Questions { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Question 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int QuizID { get; set; }
    public Quiz? Quiz { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Answer>? Answers { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Answer 
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public bool IsCorrect { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public Question? Question { get; set; }
}
```

In my `Pages\Quizzes\Details.cshtml.cs`, I am getting a Quiz model by ID and also grabbing all of it's related questions like this:

```
var quiz = await _context.Quizzes
                         .Include(quiz => quiz.Questions)
                         .FirstOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
```

Which works great, but when I inspect the `Questions` List, the `Answers` list is null. Is there a way I can modify the `_context.Quizzes.Include...` statement to also grab all `Answer` models for the `Question` for that specific Quiz ID?

Comment: `.Include(quiz => quiz.Questions).ThenInclude(question => question.Answers)`

Comment: [Including multiple levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#including-multiple-levels)